# How to Return output in R with ID numbers

Tags: r, list

I have the following program in R

```
new_route = c(0,4,5,0)

> for (i in 1:length(new_route)-1)
+ {
+     a=c(new_route[i],new_route[i+1])
+     print(a)
+ }
```

it prints as

```
[1] 0
[1] 0 4
[1] 4 5
[1] 5 0
```

but the desired output is

```
[1] 0 4
[2] 4 5
[3] 5 0
```

In future I should be able to  select a[1] or a[2] or a[3]

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could avoid the loop with `cbind(lag(new_route), new_route)[-1,]`.

Comment: cbind(head(x,-1),x[-1]) will give you the desired output

Comment: @Onyambu it works !

Answer (score 2):

This is an order of operations issue, you need parentheses.

Note the difference between `1:4 - 1` and `1:(4 - 1)`

```
> 1:4 - 1
[1] 0 1 2 3
> 1:(4 - 1)
[1] 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 0):

We can duplicate the elements in the vector, remove the first and the last one, and then printed as a matrix.

```
new_route <- c(0, 4, 5, 0)

new_route2 <- rep(new_route, each = 2)
matrix(new_route2[-c(1, length(new_route2))],
       ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    0    4
# [2,]    4    5
# [3,]    5    0
```